# Inno Setup - How to fill a button with an image in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, inno-setup-v6

Base on this question:

[How to create an image button in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129746/how-to-create-an-image-button-in-inno-setup)

How to fill the entire button with the image in Inno Setup? At the same time use different images on one button such as for, mouse click, mouse hover, disabled and normal view?

Comment: In fact, you can use an image **instead** of a button (set the `Visible := false` button property and place the image in its place) and set event handlers to the image that will do what the button does. So you can also set the image to change when you click and so on.
I may post an example later.

Comment: See also this example: https://github.com/KngStr/Inno-All-in-One-Setup/blob/master/IsPack_Restools/Inno_ISCmplr_Setup/Example/Example_MouseEvent_ImgBtn.iss

Comment: Thanks. However, is it possible to do this with the regular buttons?

Comment: **I did not check this**, but it seems that in the post you linked there is a solution for this as well (if you change the parameters X and Y and make sure that the size of the uploaded image matches the size of the button). Of course you have to hide the caption on the button in such a case... try and succeed!

Comment: @yonni I do not think that (my) code can do what you claim. Though indeed your idea with using images to implement a button is imo the easiest approach.